# How to set maxDate on Air-datepicker to 03 months

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the date of Air-datepicker from current day to 3 months or 90 days, I have created a fiddle for it.

https://jsfiddle.net/jawadanwar/m957n2fo/13/

`$('#dp').datepicker({
  language: 'en',
  autoClose: 'true',
  minDate: new Date()
})`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and post code here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to edit your question based on these guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the current date and add 90 days to that as below:

```
var maxdate = new Date(); //get current date
maxdate.setDate(maxdate.getDate() + 90); //add 90 days
$('#dp').datepicker({
  language: 'en',
  autoClose: 'true',
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: maxdate
})
```

Here's your **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/v64oeqxk/1/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)